# Required libs for Spring MVC to works like Spring Boot Cloud for AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Currently, I have 2 years old Spring MVC apps that deployed in Tomcat 8 in EC2. We required to replaces previously used messaging and pub-sub to SNS or SQS.

I already checked Spring Cloud for AWS ([here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/)) but it's for a Spring boot project, and it's too much to work if we have to refactor our 2 years old Spring MVC to boot.

Can anybody point me to a right direction (any links) on how to includes Spring libs (all necessary libs) from Spring boot AWS project into our legacy Spring app?

So I can create a controller that similar to below snippets (for SNS)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sns/receive")
public class SnsEndpointController {

@NotificationMessageMapping
public void receiveNotification(@NotificationMessage String message, 
@NotificationSubject String subject) {
    // ...
}

@NotificationSubscriptionMapping
public void confirmSubscription(NotificationStatus notificationStatus) {
    notificationStatus.confirmSubscription();
}
```

Or below snippet (for SQS)

```
@MessageMapping("logicalQueueName")
private void receiveMessage(Person person, @Header("SenderId") String 
senderId) {
    // ...
}
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Here You have necessary dependency to create controller like above

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-aws-messaging/1.0.0.RELEASE